# Resize TextField On Button Click

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to resize a `TextField`, when `startBtnClick` is clicked and I can't seem to get it to work. Basically I want to shrink the field by `110` units when the button is clicked.

**On Action** Event:

```
@FXML
protected void startBtnClick(){
    double txtWidth = this.url.getWidth();
    this.url.setPrefWidth(txtWidth - 110);
}
```

The **XML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1200.0" styleClass="anchor-pane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="phantom.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button id="beginSurfing" fx:id="quitSurfing" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#stopSurfing" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="93.00009999999747" text="Quit Surfing" visible="false" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="9.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="8.0" />
        <GridPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1200.0" style="" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
                    <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="url" disable="false" onAction="#urlGo" opacity="1.0" prefWidth="965.0" scaleZ="1.0" style="" translateZ="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="122.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="113.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="9.0">
                            <stylesheets>
                                <URL value="@../CSS/textField.css" />
                            </stylesheets>
                        </TextField>
                        <Button id="beginSurfing" fx:id="startSurfing" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#beginSurfing" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="93.00009999999747" text="Start Surfing" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="9.0" />
                        <Label fx:id="timer" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="94.0" text="" textAlignment="CENTER" underline="false" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="11.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="9.0">
                            <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Button id="beginSurfing" fx:id="nextAdBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#nextAd" prefHeight="30.000099999997474" prefWidth="94.0" text="Next Ad" visible="false" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="8.0" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
                <!--
                    The rest of the gird
                    Chopped off for readability
                -->
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I think `setPrefWidth` isn't the right method. I will test and answer

Comment: Not completely related but may give you clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304933/how-to-get-javafx-nodes-textarea-textfield-to-resize-correctly-when-user-drag

Comment: You need to set the layout parameters of the button, not just the preferred values. Android can (and often does) overrides your preferred values for the sake of efficiency and stability.

Comment: Which layout pane are you using?

Comment: I am using JavaFX Scene Builder

Comment: @zgc7009 this isn't an Android app.

Comment: @James_D I am using an Anchor Pane

Comment: That's probably the issue. Can you show the code?

Comment: @James_D Okay, I added the only other code I have for this.

Comment: Since you set the left and right anchors, it cannot be resized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your Button is in an `AnchorPane` and you have both the left and right anchors set, the width is going to be controlled by those anchors, not by the `prefWidth` property. An `AnchorPane` is probably not the best way to go if you want to be able to dynamically resize the control, but you can do

```
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(url, AnchorPane.getRightAnchor(url)+110);
```